# javascript function to press a button with condition

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello dear Javascript experts,

I have a google sheet that has an [UpdateData] button and a cell that holds dueDate. 
I would like to insert a JS code that will "Press the UpdateData button when the "Duedate" cell is equal to today's date".

something like : If "dueDate" == today then click "UpdateData".

Please share your ideas. The reason why I am thinking of JS because it is google sheet doc, not excel.

Best regards,

Comment: You need to look how google docs notices cell change events. I'm sure it's in the api documentation. Try something out and post your code if it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to add minimum code in a snippet needed to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in comments, your bet is to call a function upon an event. The following example (extracted from the original docs), is a very naive manual event which will run on a timer.

In a real application, you would want to consider some other actual event. Because the following example will run only once an hour.

```
function myFunction(){
    let updateData = document.getElementById("my_button");
    if (dueDate === new Date().toDateString()) {
        updateData.click();
    }
}

ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
  .timeBased()
  .everyHours(1)
  .create();
```

Please note that this example might not work. This is just a guide on how things will look.

Comment: Thank you. This is close of what I am trying to achieve. the button is called "Update Data". How can I include that in the function. Also, the button and the due date cell are in two different sheets. Is that Ok  ?

Comment: This helped a little bit. I got it. Thnak you

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you are trying to do, but in Javascript you can use ternary operator to check a condition. In your case, you would need to put a code like this in your button click handler :

```
"dueDate" == today ? UpdateData() : void(0)
```

Please note that I don't have any code to refer to. Also, the `void(0)` tells Javascript to do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. what I am trying to do is to automate a manual process. The process is : when the value of a cell in G Sheet == today's date then press "UpdateData" button . the button already exists within the sheet. just need the code to refer to it. please tell me if you need more context